# How can I bind simple type coming from body of the request in ASP.NET Core 5 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I tried to send a JSON object with the same name that action argument has but It seems not working I don't know what I did wrong.

My question is how to bind simple types like the example shown, without the need to create complex type that wrap my value property?

Action

```
public IActionResult Test([FromBody] string value)
{
}
```

PostMan : raw > JSON

```
{
    "value":"testValue"
}
```

Comment: Does "not working" mean the controller action is not invoked? Gets an unwanted value? Something else? If you use content-type text/plain does it do what you are looking for?

Comment: You only need the `FromBodyAttribute` once. You don't specify which property to pull from the JSON body, but you need to tell what the .NET type of the entire body is: `[FromBody] MyClass body` where `MyClass` contains your `Value` **PROPERTY**

Comment: Also, avoid using primitieve body types. Don't pull `string`, `int` or `double` from the request body, but always wrap it in a model. This avoids having untrackable bugs, and makes your code extendible

Comment: @Crowcoder mean the controller action is not invoked, I did content-type but the same problem

Comment: your parameter does not match the json being sent.... that is why it does not work.... you are sending an object and expecting a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class MyRequest {
    public string Value { get; set; }

}

//controller
IActionResult Test([FromBody] MyRequest request)
```

This should do the job.
The class/type related to the frombody object should match the whole json object and not only one property of it

This cannot work with GET requests, so try a POST

Answer (score 1):

you can use a generic model and then you could use it with any single parameter, for example

```
public class SingleModel<T>
{
    public T Value {get; set;}
}

your api method


[HttpPost]
[Consumes(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorObject),StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ResetUserPassword(
    [FromBody] SingleModel<long> model
)
{
    var id = model.Value;
}
```